"Cannot load a reference assembly for execution. BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard' or one of its dependencies"
I am getting the following error in my Visual studio 2019, ASP.NET web application project.
"Cannot load a reference assembly for execution. BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard' or one of its dependencies".
This error appeared after I removed netstandard.dll as one of the references from my project references, by right clicking mouse on the reference name, and selecting "remove".
It looks like even though I removed the reference in the manner I did, visual studio, still thinks it should be my project's reference, and tries to load it, when I try to debug my project. I have even uninstalled netstandard using NuGet Package Manager, but the error is persisting.
Before all this saga began, I did not have netstandard installed on my system. But one of the open source libraries, namely ClosedXML, which I had just started writing code around, kept asking for it by giving me an error. So I installed netstandard using NuGet Package Manager. Next I had to manually browse (using Reference Manager) to the location of netstandard.dll on my system, to add it as a reference. The Reference Manager, invoked by right clicking, on Project References, was not finding it.
Once I was finally able to add netstandard as a Reference, my project started to give me a large number of build errors on building it, 14932 to be exact, which I was not getting before. One of the error, as an example, said "'System.Object' is not defined or imported". That is why I decided to get rid of netstandard, by removing it as a reference. But now, even removing netstandard as reference is giving me an error. I have never had errors like this before. Everything was working. I regret getting entagled in netstandard. One more detail, just in case it matters, in order to get netstandard available as a refernce, I had also installed Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility. I do not know if it had any positive effect or not. Another detail, in case its relevant, my project's target .NET Framework is 4.7.2

Usually these crazy system.object cannot be found errors go away with a restart or a reboot. You can also try deleting your bin and obj folders and do a full clean/rebuild. You shouldn't need to "reference" .netstandard as it is an interface that 4.7.2 implements. Ideally you can just revert your project back to before you installed .netstandard (assuming you are using version control).

Thank you topsail. I backed up my bin & obj folder by renaming them so that visual studio thinks they are deleted. Then I cleaned & rebuilt. But when I did that, my code threw an exception when I tried to connect to my LocalProcessDB.sdf.  I am showing the 2 of the lines of code, below. The 2nd line gives exception.
builderLocal.DataSource = @"|DataDirectory|\LocalProcessDB.sdf";
localConn = new SqlCeConnection(builderLocal.ConnectionString);
The exception said the following: Unable to load the native components of SQL Server Compact corresponding to the ADO.NET provider of version 8876. Install the correct version of SQL Server Compact. Refer to KB article 974247 for more details.
So I looked up StackOverflow. Here is a link to relevant response.
Unable to load the native components of SQL Server Compact corresponding to the ADO.NET provider
From this I got the idea to copy the amd64 & x86 folders, from my backed up bin folder, into the new bin folder.
And from what I can see so far, things are working again. The problem is gone at least. So thanks again. If anybody else wants to post an additional, more detailed answer, they are welcome to do so.
